# How to edit the insert options for existing content using that template?

Tags: templates

I'm VERY new to Sitecore so forgive me, if this question doesn't make any sense.

I've added an insert option to the `__StandardValues` of a template. I expect the content using this template to have the this new insert option but it doesn't.

Is there another step to this?

or do changes to templates not affect those content that have already been created using the template...

Comment: You cannot see templates in insert options as admin or regular content editors?

Comment: I'm logged in as admin

Comment: If you create a new item from this template, does it have the right insert options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a normal behavior.

You need to reset the insert options of the item to see the changes on standard values,if you create items based on a template and then you add to the standardvalues of template new insert options.

Please have a look on below picture. You need to press Reset button from Insert Options section.

If you create new items based on the template you will see the changes from Standard Value.

[image]

If you want to reset InsertOptions of an item  you can do it programatically using:

1. C# Code:

   item.Fields["__Masters"].Reset();
2. Using Powershell Extension :

   Example: Get-Item "master:/sitecore/content/home" | Reset-ItemField -IncludeStandardFields -Name "__Masters"

Comment: Will that apply the change to all items, or will I need to do this manually to each item using the changed template?

Comment: it will apply just to the current item

Comment: So if I already had 1000 pages using that template, and I change the insert options, I would have to go through 1000 pages and hit the "Reset Templates" button one by one?

Comment: Use Sitecore Powershell extension.

Comment: Ok - I don't have 1000 pages but was just wondering. thanks

Comment: I've noticed the `InsertItems` on some of the content using the template are not the same, they've been manually edited I guess. Is it possible to create a powershell script that adds an `InsertItem` to all content using a particular template? - The script given above looks like it would be too agressive and I'd lose manually added `InsertItems`

Answer (score 2):

## Reset Insert Options field to standard values

If the Insert options field of the item was previously edited, it will have its own value instead of taking its value from the `__Standard Values` item for that template. (This is true even if you updated the item's value back to what was stored in the `__Standard Values` item).

To remove the item-specific value and fall back to the standard value, you can use the **Reset** button:

1. In the Content Editor, under the **View** ribbon tab, check the **Standard fields** checkbox to show standard fields, of which the Insert options field (technically called `__Masters`) is one.
2. In the **Versions** ribbon tab, click the **Reset** button:

   [image: Reset Field Values dialog]
3. Check the box next to the **Insert options** field and click the **Reset** button.